# Remove or rename default release-profile in Maven

Tags: java, maven, release

The `Super POM` of Maven provides a `release-profile` with some default settings. Unfortunately, this profile name interfeers with our naming conventions of profiles. Thus, in the profile selection, this profile stands out and has no real purpose.

**Is there a way to remove the profile? Or at least rename it?**

Comment: Can you please write which Maven version you are using? In which profile selection?

Comment: Maven 3.6.3 - Proflie selection in NetBeans 12.5

Comment: That's convenience of Netbeans to show such things..usually you don't need profiles at all ...apart from that this profile can not be removed because it's part of Apache Maven itself...apart from that this profile is there for a very long time...